# F# access tuple member in a lambda

Tags: lambda, f#

I have a `groups` which of type `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal list list`, I am trying to generate a `decimal list`, with each element is the summation of the fourth element in the inner list of `groups`.
My try is as follow,

```
groups
|> List.map(fun x -> (List.reduce (fun acc elem -> elem + acc ))
```

`elem` is suppose to be a  `DateTime*int*decimal*decimal`, my question is how to access the fourth element of the tuple in the above lambda?

Answer (score 7):

You can decompose the tuple in the lambda parameter declaration: `fun (_,_,d,_) -> d` will return the 3rd element of a tuple.

You can also simplify your code by using `List.sumBy` instead of `List.reduce`.

```
//sample data
let groups = [
    [(System.DateTime(), 1, 1.5M, 2.5M); (System.DateTime(), 1, 4.1M, 2.5M)]
    [System.DateTime(), 1, 3.2M, 2.5M]
]

groups
|> List.map (List.sumBy (fun (_,_,d,_) -> d))
```